# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

```
namespace Exer3
{
    public partial class MyCalculator : Form
    {
        public MyCalculator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   

            int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtNum1.Text);
            int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtNum2.Text);

            if (txtNum1.Text.Length == 0 & txtNum2.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Input Detected");
                txtNum1.Focus();
                txtNum2.Focus();
            }
            else

            lblTotal.Text = (num1 + num2).ToString();



        }

        }
    }
```

when i run the program and it calculates well.. but when i try to leave the textbox empty and click the add button the messagebox will appear with "no input detected" after that the program will start debugging and it says "Input string was not in a correct format". please help to solve this problem

Comment: Any question? Also make sure you enter numbers to textboxes

Comment: It would help a lot if you'd give a little more description of the problem. Is the title what you get when you try to compile this, or run it, or what exactly?

Comment: replace your Convert.ToInt32 with int.TryParse() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx

Answer (score 2):

change these lines as

```
int num1 = Convert.ToInt32("0"+txtNum1.Text);
int num2 = Convert.ToInt32("0"+txtNum2.Text);
```

OR Use `int.TryParse`

Answer (score 0):

thr problem here is that you are converting the textbox which you don't know if it contains a valid number or not, try this one

```
if (txtNum1.Text.Length == 0 && txtNum2.Text.Length == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("No Input Detected");
    txtNum1.Focus();
    txtNum2.Focus();
}
else
{
    int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtNum1.Text);
    int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtNum2.Text);
    lblTotal.Text = (num1 + num2).ToString();
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for solving my problem.. :)